# How can I program Mega2560 with Atmel Studio 6.2

Tags: arduino, atmel, atmel-studio

I have got the [SainSmart Mega2560](http://cgi.ebay.de/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=221232715892&ssPageName=STRK:MESE:IT).

The problem is now: how can I program it with Atmel Studio 6.2?

I can find no way to upload code, because the controller is not in listed and with ISP I can not do it, because STK600 is needed which I don't have!

Is there another way to program the Mega2560 with Atmel Studio 6.2?

Comment: The ATmega2560 is listed in my version of Studio 6.2. It can be programmed with all the usual devices including the Dragon and Atmel ICE.

Comment: The link says it's for Arduino, so there is likely a bootloader already flashed. As such, you can very likely just use the Arduino IDE as LightTrepidation suggests below.

Comment: it is easier to program with Arduino software than with ATMEL Studio, but i have to learn it for my study....only thing -> the USB-ISP programmer works with STK500 protocol and for the 2560 STK600 is needed...do you know which programmer does support that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the Ardiuno IDE? Unless you know what you are doing, its much easier to preserve the bootloader this way. I expect the support is based from that viewpoint also.

Comment: it is easier to program with Arduino software than with ATMEL Studio, but i have to learn it for my study....only thing -> the USB-ISP programmer works with STK500 protocol and for the 2560 STK600 is needed...do you know which programmer does support that ?

Comment: There are guides on how to do this. The programmer on board appears to be supported as a generic USB to Serial Programmer. [link](http://www.engblaze.com/tutorial-using-atmel-studio-6-with-arduino-projects/). Don't worry too much about the STK part - they are just another means of programming the chip.

Comment: Thank you so much for your link. It is really useful. Cheers!